# Passing html from an AsyncTask object back to the calling Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have an activity object, myAct.  myAct creates and calls my httpGetter object which extends AsyncTask

httpGetter does a great job!  My progress bars work great.  It gets the HTML data. I put a toast in the httpGetter.onPostExecute..... There's the HTML!!!!

How do I pass that data back to the activity from the onPostExecute?  I don't even know what to google for this.  I tried a few things, and all of the examples I saw either updated a textView or just showed the data in a toast, right in the onPostExecute.  I want to resume things back in the calling Activity.  In my httpGetter class, I created a method to set a handle to the calling Activity thinking I could call a method with the result String.  No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so a bit more googling came up with the following solution.

myAct needed an interface

```
   public interface WebServiceListener 
{
    public void onHTTPGetComplete (ArrayList<String> arrayList);
}
public void onHTTPGetComplete  (ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
      String Response = arrayList.get(0);
      Toast worked = Toast.makeText(mainPage.this, Response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      worked.show();
}
```

and the Async in the onPostExecute needed to call it

> listener.onHTTPGetComplete (myList);

Answer (score 0):

How about sending an intent from httpGetter to myAct  with intent.putExtra() to pass back your data?  For this to work, you'll need to let httpGetter know about myAct's context when you create the AsyncTask.

Comment: I've also thought about this solution but worry of the overhead on first broadcasting the intend and listening for it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass back a bundle from your AsyncTask with the HTML in it. Example:

```
@Override
protected Bundle doInBackground(String... params) {

    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet("myurl");

    HttpResponse response = HttpManager.execute(get);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String raw_result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    entity.consumeContent();

    b.putString(IService.RESULT, raw_result);
    b.putInt(IService.STATUS, IService.STATUS_FINISHED);

    return b;

}


// override this in your activity as an anon inner class
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bundle b) {
    int resultCode = b.getInt(IService.STATUS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was add an abstract consumer method to my HttpAsyncTask to which I would pass the data the server returned from onPostExecute. Now the activity calling it needs to implement the consumer method , giving the activity access to the data :-)